# How to make a motion sensor circuit, that can communicate with my LAN?

Tags: sensors, wifi, communication, circuit

I'm a newbie to Electronics/ Robotics, but I love to do it as a hobby.

So I want to build a circuit (a really small in size would be much better) with a motion sensor that can communicate data (Basically when it sense a motion send a signal) to my computer over Wifi. Is this something possible? 
If so how do I do it, may be a schematics diagram, or someway to start the project would be a grate help.

Thank you!!

Comment: How small is small?  Easiest is get a board with a CPU and Wifi and hook it to your sensor.

Comment: Yes thats would be an option too, but I'm looking for some sort of a circuit, that just do the exact job. If I get something like RPI to do this, I reckon thats waste of resources

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that WiFi protocols are kind of complex and so you'll almost certainly need a CPU in there to handle this.  That doesn't preclude miniaturization but it'll be a bigger challenge if you don't want to use an available board.

Comment: One more thing that I want to take in to account is power source, it should run on 4.5 - 6v max (3 - 4 AA Batteries??)I reckon. Would you mind recommend me some board out there? That would be really helpful. Thanx

Comment: The only board I've personally used that had WiFi was the PandaBoard...  I'm sure Google can find lots of other options.  This seems to be an interesting option: http://electricimp.com/

Comment: Two things: 1.) Is this a robotics question? Or would EE and maybe SE be more appropriate? 2.) I would personally use Arduino and add use [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-and-Easy-Arduino-Wi-Fi-Hack/).

Comment: Hi Thanu, and welcome to *robotics*.  Unfortunately, broad questions about how to approach a general problem
aren't something that a stack exchange site is good for. We prefer *[practical,
answerable questions based on actual problems that you 
face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)*. Take a look at [ask] and 
[about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and hopefully we can 
modify this question into something a bit more answerable.  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yep point taken..and thanx